# Why does the following code return an error when consuming multiple endpoints of a WCF service?

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0

I have created a multi-endpoint WCF service and consumed and it is working fine.

But when I am trying to close the service client then am getting error.

This is how I am creating the client object and disposing its working fine for single endpoint WCF service

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ICardPrintingService Service = null;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Service = new CardPrintingServiceClient();
            var response = this.Service.GetCardData(new GetCardDataRequest { NIK = 6666620501740003 });
            try
            {
                ((CardPrintingServiceClient)Service).Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is going to the catch block when closing the connection with error message

> The remote endpoint no longer recognizes this sequence. This is most
>   likely due to an abort on the remote endpoint. The value of
>   wsrm:Identifier is not a known Sequence identifier. The reliable
>   session was faulted.

Can some one tell me why?

Thanks a ton in adv

Raghavendra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the need of casting overhere.

```
((CardPrintingServiceClient)Service).Close(); //pls explain this.
```

you can try this in finally block.

```
if (Service.State != System.ServiceModel.CommunicationState.Closed)
  {
     Service.Abort();
  }
```

Comment: as i have created the object for interface i exposed via service i will not able to close the service as Service.Close so i will type cast the service to Service client and then need to close and thanks for the update will try it

Comment: Thanks a lot userGS this solved the issue but will post the stats after complete diagnostics